# How to remove Twitter names from a string with regex

Tags: regex, string, twitter

I would like to remove all twitter nicknames (@xxx) from a string like this:

Hi @xxx and @yyy and @zzz.

I would like to get a string that will contain only (Hi and and).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP:**

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\s+|^)@\S+/', '', $Text);
```

**Perl:**

```
$text =~ s/(\s+|^)@\S+//g;
```

---

*Optionally you can use `\w+` (word characters) instead of `\S+` (non-whitespace characters).*

Comment: Probably `\w+` is a better choice, otherwise you'll trim off trailing punctuation too!

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP, you can use `preg_replace` function :

```
<?php
   $str = "Hi @xxx and @yyy and @zzz.";
   echo preg_replace('/@\w+/', '', $str);
?>
```

`/@\w+/` will search for every at sign followed by a word.

For each name found, you just have to replace it by an empty string.

Comment: This will mess up any emails that the string may contain, you should make sure the @ isn't part of an email address.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby version of the code:

```
/\A[^@]+\z/
```